# In PHP, what's the diff between 'stripcslashes' and 'stripslashes'?

Tags: php

just.... don't know why two strip slash function.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

stripcslashes() skips special character sets like "\n" and "\r", preserving any line breaks, return carriages, etc. that may be in the string.

stripslashes() simply removes any slashes it encounters without parsing anything beforehand.

Answer (score 18):

`stripcslashes` does not simply skip the C-style escape sequences `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and `\v`, but converts them to their actual meaning. So

```
stripcslashes('\n') == "\n"
```

while

```
stripslashes('\n') == "n"
```

Note that `'\n' == "\\n"`.